# How to download an exe file using curl, then the link doesnt contain the exe file in windows

Tags: windows, curl, download

How do i find the link to the exe located at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2108834&Channel=Stable&language=en (Edge Browser for Microsoft) so that I can use curl to download the exe file?

I tried `curl https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2108834&Channel=Stable&language=en` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify what you want to do with the contents of the file.
In this case save to a new file.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2108834&Channel=Stable&language=en' --output foo.exe
```